# Pass path with space as parameter of executable via Process.Start

Tags: c#, filepath

I have path with backslashes and space that I need to send as parameter to regedit.exe:

```
\\folder1\folder2\folder three\file.reg
```

Based on my knowledge using `@` in front of string should allow back slashes to be specified directly (without escaping). Here is my full code that I am trying to execute it on:

```
string path = @"\\folder1\folder2\folder three\file.reg"
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", file);
```

When I tried running the program, it gives me an error from regedit's output  saying:

> Cannot import \folder1\folder2\folder: Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error

Since error report backslashes correctly I am guessing the compiler or regedit does not read anything past the whitespace after "folder"

Comment: What do you mean "it only reads up to"?

Comment: `"But it only reads up to"` - what is _"it"_?

Comment: @DaveZych It doesn't read anything past the whitespace in between "folder" and "three". It only reads everything before that

Comment: Yes, and what is *it*?

Comment: @DaveZych I added my code to clarify it more. Sorry about that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When passing arguments in the command line, you need to surround them with `"`. Try this:

```
string path = @"""\\folder1\folder2\folder three\file.reg""";
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", path);
```

Adding `""` in a verbatim string will add a single double quote to the string so the resulting string will be `"\\folder1\folder2\folder three\file.reg"` which will then allow it to get passed correctly to `regedit.exe`.